# Fix classloading issue with ByteBuddy and Vaadin in OSGi setup

Tags: java, osgi, vaadin, byte-buddy, vaadin-flow

I have issues with Vaadin flow in an OSGi setup and it seems to be related to the way some classes are loaded in the internals, when using Polymer Templates.
Here is my issue with some details https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/7377.

In `TemplateModelProxyHandler:229ff` the following code is used to load the Proxy Class

```
Class<?> proxyType = proxyBuilder

// Handle bean methods (and abstract methods for error handling)
.method(method -> isAccessor(method) || method.isAbstract())
.intercept(MethodDelegation.to(proxyHandler))

// Handle internal $stateNode methods
.defineField("$stateNode", StateNode.class)
.method(method -> "$stateNode".equals(method.getName()))
.intercept(FieldAccessor.ofField("$stateNode"))

// Handle internal $modelType methods
.defineField("$modelType", BeanModelType.class)
.method(method -> "$modelType".equals(method.getName()))
.intercept(FieldAccessor.ofField("$modelType"))

// Create the class
.name(proxyClassName).make()
.load(classLoader, ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
.getLoaded();
```

Here, two Class Loaders are important. First, the OSGi Bundle ClassLoader (`classLoader`) here. Second, the classloader of the Bundle which contains the class `TemplateModelProxyHandler`, e.g. `TemplateModelProxyHandler.class.getClassLoader()`.
Is there a way to use both classloaders here?
Is there a simple method to achieve that with ByteBuddy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look into the `MultipleParentClassLoader` that is shipped with Byte Buddy. It allows you to specify multiple parents to a class loader and define a class within it.

Comment: Hi Rafael, thanks for the reply. So simply exchanging `classLoader` in the `load` method with the `MultipleParentClassLoader` should then do the trick? Will try it later!

Comment: In theory, yes.

Comment: It also works in practice, thank you very much Rafael!